# The pernicious USB-stick stall problem. Is it fixed in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, usb, hard-drive

There's a known bug in Ubuntu that causes the system to freeze when copying files to a external hard drive (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107703/56755 and 
http://lwn.net/Articles/572911/). I can testify that this bug is still a problem in 13.10.

Is this issue fixed in version 14.04, or 14.04.1?

Comment: The LWN article says it's likely to fixed by kernel version 3.13, and 13.10 only had 3.11, whereas 14.04 has 3.13. I'd guess it's fixed.

Comment: If there's an official bug report, have a look at it. If it says it's fixed, then it should be.

Comment: @the_Seppi I don't know if there's an official bug report. If there is one, I haven't found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63531), which was closed as `INVALID`.
The patch to fix this (at least, that's what I think it does from a quick scan of the mailing list discussion) was originally submitted in [November](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1590821). However, it has only entered the `linux-next` tree [*today*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/?h=akpm&id=af86fefe413b6b1542e1b0f97be8bc9570c5eaf7). And from what I understand of the `linux-next` tree, code merged in to it are aimed at the next release. So, no, the bug hasn't been fixed yet, but will be (hopefully soon).

Comment: On the other hand, people are saying that kernel 3.13 fixes this issue, and kernel 3.13 is included in Ubuntu 14.04. How can I be sure? Has anyone with Ubuntu 14.04 (or 14.04.1) experienced this issue?

Comment: @becko for what it's worth, I was the commenter on the question who talked about 3.13. But note that that was a guess based on the lwn article's prediction that the patch would be included in 3.13, a prediction which didn't come true.